# How to add Foreign Key association manually in LinQ Mapping?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Hello I'm trying to generate a table in LinQ. I have a foreign key but I don't know how to define this relationship. Here's my code:

```
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;


[Table]
public class Resources
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public int ResourceId { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public string ResourceDesc { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public string LanguageId { get; set; }

}
[Table]
public class Languages
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string LanguageDesc { get; set; }
}
```

So, I want `LanguageId` in `Resources` table to reference as a foreign key the `LanguageId` in `Languages` table. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You should use the AssociationAttribute to map the reference.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.associationattribute(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I took a look but I can't figure a way to add foreign key still. there are partial classes, customers in orders etc..

Answer (score 0):

you can define Foreign Key using EntityRef

```
    public int LanguageID{ get; set; }
    private EntityRef<Languages> _relatedLanguage= new 
    EntityRef<Languages>();
    [Association(IsForeignKey =true, ThisKey = "LanguageID", Storage = 
    "_relatedLanguage")]
    public Languages RelatedLanguage
    {
        get { return _relatedLanguage.Entity; }
        set { _relatedLanguage.Entity = value; }
```